# Error with Substring()

Tags: powershell

```
$fileName = "Name of TheFolder_NE_ED"
$lengthFileName = $fileName.length
$shortenLengthFileName = $lengthFileName - 5
Write-Host("Name of TheFolder_NE_ED").Substring($shortenLengthFileName,$lengthFileName)
$x = $host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey("NoEcho,IncludeKeyDown")
```

I am having a problem with `SubString()` function, it errors with:

[image: error message]

I tried printing out values of my variables but they seemed fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PowerShell, substring works in a slightly different way.

With your existing code you could try this:

```
$fileName = "Name of TheFolder_NE_ED"
$lengthFileName = $fileName.length
$shortenLengthFileName = $lengthFileName - 5
Write-Host("Name of TheFolder_NE_ED").Substring($shortenLengthFileName)
```

**Explanation:**

The first parameter inside Substring should be the starting index of the character(in this case 18). Now from that letter it will start counting till the character (which you have to pass as a second parameter). Else it will by default go to the end of the string.

So, if you want to pass 2 parameters and do that, then change it to:

```
Write-Host("Name of TheFolder_NE_ED").Substring($shortenLengthFileName,5)
```

For further reference, follow [Substring Use](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692804.aspx)

Hope it helps.

Comment: Different from what? A zero based index and length is quite common (batch, vbscript, jscript). The mistake was using the length out of bounds.

Comment: Here the length is 23. Could you please try `.substring(18,20)`..and try the same in Java also once.

Comment: The count again starts from the first parameter's index value.

Comment: I won't criticise your solution Ranadip, I don't speak java ;-)  If index + length exceed the whole string length any language will error out, ignore the overhang or present erroneous data.

Comment: @LotPings: Yup, thats what I am trying to say. It will be erroneous  :)